# Как получить boolean значение из checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

У меня есть input с типом checkbox, при событии я отправляю на сервер его value.
Вот код

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="url_chek_1" class="url_chek" onchange = "get_u(this.id, this.value)"/>
```

Но я получаю только "1", тоесть и при включение и при выключение this.value = "1", я хочу получать при включении одно значении, а при выключении другое.

Comment: Всё потому, что `value="1"`, а `onchange` отслеживает событие установки/снятия "галочки" и выполняет отправку `get_u(this.id, this.value)`, отправлять надо состояние `checkbox.checked`..

Answer (score 0):

```
onchange="get_u(this.id, this.checked? this.value : 0)"
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]